# Why am I finding peculiar B cell population when pbmcs are cultured for 3 days with CD40L?

Tags: cell-biology, immunology, flow-cytometry, cell-sorting

While performing intracellular cytokine assay on B cells, I am finding a peculiar population.
I use 2*10^6 cells for studying each functional marker. The pbmcs are cultured for 72 hours, with CD40L dose being given in 0 hour after plating and BFA in the 48th hour. When analysed, I am getting two CD19+ populations from the lymphocytes. Can anyone enlighten me about what actually is happening?

Comment: Have you phenotyped the populations further, other than using CD19 after presumably gating on CD3-? How are you detecting the two populations of CD19+? Are you plotting CD19 vs another marker, or is it simply CD19 intensity? Can you share your plots and gating strategy, comparing untreated vs treated? Also, what is BFA - brefeldin A?